# Center the adobe edge animate stage and preloader horizontal and vertical

Tags: adobe-edge

I have made a Adobe Edge animation.
Now I want to center the animation and the preloader, so that's always being shown
horizonaly and verticaly centered in my browser.

Please help me.

I found the following thread:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/979124?promoid=KBHBD

But nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to center and resize the stage so that it will fit window.
You can simply remove the resize part if you don't want to resize but just to center.
You can paste this code on the window.resize event of the Stage component (Window > Code > Stage > Event > Resize).

```
var stageHeight = $("#Stage").height();
var stageWidth = $("#Stage").width();
// console.log("stageHeight " + stageHeight);
// console.log("stageWidth " + stageWidth);
var ratio = stageWidth / stageHeight;
var bodyHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
// console.log("bodyHeight " + bodyHeight);
// console.log("bodyWidth " + bodyWidth);
var bodyRatio = bodyWidth / bodyHeight;
var newStageHeight = bodyHeight;
var newStageWidth = bodyWidth;
var leftPos = 0;
var topPos = 0;
// fit width
if (bodyRatio < ratio) {
    newStageWidth = bodyWidth;
    newStageHeight = newStageWidth / ratio;
    topPos = 0.5 * (bodyHeight - newStageHeight);
}
// fit height
else if (ratio < bodyRatio) {
    newStageHeight = bodyHeight;
    newStageWidth = newStageHeight * ratio;
    leftPos = 0.5 * (bodyWidth - newStageWidth);
}
// console.log("newStageHeight " + newStageHeight);
// console.log("newStageWidth " + newStageWidth);
$("#Stage").height(newStageHeight);
$("#Stage").width(newStageWidth);
$("#Stage").css("left", leftPos + 'px');
$("#Stage").css("top", topPos + 'px');
```

Comment: Hi Ena,
thank you for your comment - but it doesn't work for me.

Please take a look at the following testpage from me:

http://openoffice.funpic.de/Test_002/test002.html

 

You can download the complete composition (includes Edge Animation Source file):

http://openoffice.funpic.de/Test_002/Test_002.rar

Comment: If you resize browser window you will see that the code actually works :] Only problem left is that on page load the event is not fired. Please add the exact same code also to the event compositionReady (Window > Code > Stage > Event > CompositionReady).

Comment: Hi - that's right - I tried this:
it's only indented but not centered horizontally
and it's still on top of the page.
You can take a look at this version of my tests:
http://openoffice.funpic.de/Test_004/test004.html
http://openoffice.funpic.de/Test_004/Test_004.rar

Please also take a look at Version 003.....i tried another code and this works perfectly with Firefox (horizontally and vertically centered), but NOT with Internet Explorer :(